# How can I get the selected radio button value on another jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp

This is the 1st page. I'm facing problem with the radio button value being NULL on the submission handling page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>LoginForm</title>
  </head>
<body >

<font size="20"><marquee behavior="alternate">Spice Digital</marquee></font>
  <h1>Login Page</h1>
    <h2>Signup Details</h2>
    <form action="LoginCheck.jsp" method="post">
      <br/>Username:<input type="text" name="username">
      <br/>Password:<input type="password" name="password">

      <br/>select your gender:
      <select name=dropdown>
        <option name=one value=one> Male </option>
        <option name=two value=two> Female </option>
      </select>

      <br/>select your department:
      <input type="radio" name=myradio value="1"/>MCA
      <input type="radio" name=myradio value="2"/>B.Tech
      <input type="radio" name=myradio value="3"/>Other

      <br/> select your choices:
      <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="1"/>java
      <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="2"/>c++
      <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="3"/>c
      <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="4"/>sql

      <br/>enter you comments here:
      <textarea name=mytextarea cols=20 rows=5>
      </textarea>

      <br/><input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the 2nd page. I'm unable to get the selected value here. Am I using `request.getParameter()` wrong?.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSP Page</title>
  </head>
<body BACKGROUND="C:\Documents and Settings\temp-      00940\workspace\login\WebContent\background.jpg">      
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <form action="LoginForm.jsp"  method="get">
      <font size="20"><marquee>Spice Digital </marquee></font>
        <h2>

        <%          
        String a=session.getAttribute("username").toString();
        out.println("Welcome "+a+"..!!");
        %>
        <br>
        <%
        String b=request.getParameter("myradio");
        out.println("Your department is "+b);
        %>
        <br/>
        <%
        String c=request.getParameter("mybox");
        out.println("Your choice is "+c);
        %>
        </h2>
        <br/>
        <a href="http://www.Google.com">Click here to google search</a>
        <br/>
        <br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/>
     <a href="Logout.jsp">LogOut</a>
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is malformed. Don't forget your quotes `""`.

Comment: Are you getting any Expection

Comment: Are you getting any NULLPointerExpection... what is the need of form in the second jsp.. its working with radio button

Comment: no exception. it just returns null. the output is  "Your department is null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine with me on eclipse.
Modified the code a little for simplicity.

If not routing data to some other page then In  in this you should have the name of your JSP file which your data should get displayed.

Here is the modified code.

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>LoginForm</title>
</head>
<body >

<font size="20"><marquee behavior="alternate">Spice Digital</marquee></font>
    <h1>Login Page</h1>
        <h2>Signup Details</h2>
        <form action="new.jsp" method="post">
        <br/>Username:<input type="text" name="username">
        <br/>Password:<input type="password" name="password">

        <br/>select your gender:
        <select name=dropdown>
        <option name=one value=one> Male </option>
        <option name=two value=two> Female </option>
        </select>

        <br/>select your department:
        <input type="radio" name=myradio value="1"/>MCA
        <input type="radio" name=myradio value="2"/>B.Tech
        <input type="radio" name=myradio value="3"/>Other

        <br/> select your choices:
        <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="1"/>java
        <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="2"/>c++
        <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="3"/>c
        <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="4"/>sql

        <br/>enter you comments here:
        <textarea name=mytextarea cols=20 rows=5>
        </textarea>


        <br/><input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**new.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body BACKGROUND="C:\Documents and Settings\temp-00940\workspace\login\WebContent\background.jpg">      
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <form action="LoginForm.jsp"  method="get">
      <font size="20"><marquee>Spice Digital </marquee></font>
        <h2>

        <%          
       // String a=session.getAttribute("username").toString();
      //  out.println("Welcome "+a+"..!!");
        %>
        <br>
        <%
        String b=request.getParameter("myradio");
        out.println("Your department is "+b);
        %>
        <br/>
        <%
        String c=request.getParameter("mybox");
        out.println("Your choice is "+c);
        %>
        </h2>
        <br/>
        <a href="http://www.Google.com">Click here to google search</a>
        <br/>
        <br/><br/>
        <br/><br/><br/>
    <a href="Logout.jsp">LogOut</a>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

problem could be with you routing as you are sending your form first to logincheck.jsp then to your desired jsp.

Comment: i have to route it to logincheck.jsp first to check the username and password

Comment: Then you should make sure that your radio data is also passed through it or get saved in a model.
or you can set/save your radio data in some session or Model to access it.

Comment: It's working now . i was not saving it in a session in the LoginCheck Page. Thank you so much..!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form-name" action="LoginCheck.jsp" method="post">

     <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1" checked="checked"/>MCA
     <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2"/>B.Tech
     <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="3"/>Other

    <input name="goto" type="submit" value="Login"> 
</form>

</body>
</html
```

Fetching request values:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" %>
<%
    String myRadio= request.getParameter("myradio");
%>
```

To determine which button is selected, use `request.getParameter("myradio")`

For values processing:

```
if ("1".equals(myRadio)) {
   // processing here       
}
```

Comment: it's still giving the same output "your department is null". i'm unable to figure out what's wrong..!!

Comment: what about other parameters? are they getting displayed ?

Comment: @san no  the check box is also returning null, but if i figure out how to get the radio button value, then i can fix the rest aswell. it is only returning the username correctly.

Comment: Does that answer from @AngularHarsh help u ?

Comment: regarding the routing. i have to route it to logincheck.jsp first to check the username and password.

Comment: yes. tried it.. same result. but if i'm making two separate pages dedicated for this task. i.e one page only for radio buttons and another only for getting the values.. it is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

i guess its because you have not specified the value for name attribute within quotes ,

**Name is getting displayed because you have it inside quotes,**

```
 <br/>Username:<input type="text" name="username">
```

So try this,

```
select your gender:
        <select name="dropdown">
        <option name="one" value="one> Male </option>
        <option name="two" value="two"> Female </option>
        </select>

        <br/>select your department:
        <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="1"/>MCA
        <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="2"/>B.Tech
        <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="3"/>Other

        <br/> select your choices:
        <input type="checkbox" name="mybox" value="1"/>java
        <input type="checkbox" name="mybox"value="2"/>c++
        <input type="checkbox" name="mybox"value="3"/>c
        <input type="checkbox" name="mybox"value="4"/>sql

        <br/>enter you comments here:
        <textarea name="mytextarea" cols=20 rows=5>
        </textarea>
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: tried it.. same result. but if i'm making two seperate pages dedicated for this task. i.e one page only for radio buttons and another only for getting the values.. it is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

My answer may be of use for others:

I will show it with an example for both radio and drop-down buttons as both are used to select a singular response from a list:
File: index.jsp

```
<form action="./StudentServlet" method="post">
    <div class="form-label-group">
        <label for="studentCourses">Student Course Group</label>
        <select id="studentCourses" name="studentCourses">
            <%for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {%>
                <option value= "1ITF<%=i%>">1ITF<%=i%></option>
            <%}%>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-label-group">
        <label for="studentPreference">Preference at the moment:</label>
        <%String[] chosenArray = {"APP", "BIT", "EMDEV", "INFRA", "ANDR"};
      for (int j = 0; j < chosenArray.length; j++) {%>
        <p><input type="radio" name="studentPreference" value="<%=chosenArray[j]%>" id="<%=chosenArray[j]%>"/>
            <label for="<%=chosenArray[j]%>"><%=chosenArray[j]%></label> 
        </p>
      <%}%>
      <input type="submit" name="studentFormSubmit" id="studentFormSubmit">
    </div>
</form>
```

File: StudentServlet.java

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String studentCourse = request.getParameter("studentCourses");
    String studentPreference = request.getParameter("studentPreference");

    Student coursePreference= new Student(studentCourse, studentPreference);

    if (request.getParameter("studentFormSubmit") != null) {
        request.setAttribute("coursePreference", coursePreference);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("DisplayResult.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } 
}
```

And in file DisplayResult.jsp

```
<h1>Course Details</h1>
<div>
    <%
    Student coursePreference= = (Student) request.getAttribute("coursePreference");
    %>

    <p>Student Course: <%=coursePreference.getStudentCourse()%></p>
    <p>Student Preference: <%=coursePreference.getStudentPreference()%></p>
</div>
```